# Tomcat JSP:How to laod multiple JSP file in one go

Tags: multithreading, jsp

I need to execute multiple DIV on JSP parallel/concurrently.

There is 6 DIVS, each DIV fire some http request to server. Now there is requirement to excute set of request in parallel.

e.g  There is A.jsp which contains DIV A, DIV B, DIV C, DIV D. Now I want load all four div to execute at a time parallel while loading of A.jsp.

Right now it's executing sequentially.

Comment: Last sentence *reply ASAP* should **not** be there. But details are required. Currently, it is unclear what you want : multithreading server side while executing JSP, multiple downloads from client, other ?

Comment: How are those divs populated?

Comment: Sending Http Request under IMG SRC tag in side the DIV , using struts tag lib, and the request is inside iterator

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to send request to another JSP.

Code like this in A.jsp:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'B.jsp',
     data: data ,
     success: success ,
     dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Hello Jason , thanks for your reply, i have edited the question, so please reply if possible.

Comment: I believe it is impossible to load elements by multiple parallel. Because web browser render html and css in single thread.